# Unable to create table from query

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have the following query

```
CREATE TABLE grades_gra (
  id_gra INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  identifier_gra VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  name_gra VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id_gra)
)
ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

When I execute it, it gives me an error `invalid default vale for 'naes_gra'`

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? What you gave has at least one typo which makes it harder to diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a comma before `primary key`:

```
CREATE TABLE grades_gra (
  id_gra INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  identifier_gra VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  name_gra VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_gra)
)
ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98569)

Answer (score 1):

Put the comma after DEFAULT NULL, before PRIMARY keyword